# Please explain the bars

Tags: notation

I was trying to play a piece of music on my keyboard when I got stuck at this bar no.17 (Please refer to the pic below).
Can someone please explain how do a rest symbol and a whole note appear one upon another? How to play these two bars?
Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the stem directions pointing up for one voice and those pointing down for another voice, you will see it's *two voices on one stave*. You could show it on two staves like this...

[image]

Notating it on one staff basically means play it with *one hand* unless other markings tell to use two hands.

Now, notice the fingering numbers on the two parts. The `5` above the `A` means play it with your pinky. While you hold that for four beats you use fingers `1 2 3` - thumb, index, middle - to play the other part, notes `D E F#`.

So, you sort of split the fingers of your hand into two groups and working them separately. In this case the top group is just `5` and the bottom group is `1 2 3`. The fingers could be split up into different groupings depending on the particular passage.

If this is new to you, try looking up "five finger exercises." That's a common keyboard method. You want to find the type that have some fingers stay down while the others move, in one hand. *Finger independence* is the goal of the practice.

The passage you gave just happens to fit into a five finger position - five adjacent steps of a scale - but this kind of two part texture could happen with larger intervals like a sixth or octave. Starting practice with the smaller five finger position would be normal.

Answer (score 4):

bar 17: Hold the A down with your pinky for the entire duration of the bar, while playing the melody with your other four fingers (ref. the fingerings on your score)

bar 18: Release your pinky as you play the F# with probably your middle finger. Then jump to a higher position to play the rest.

This is a simple example of two voices in one hand, which is abundant in piano repertoire.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as two instruments.  One has the whole note, the other has the rest and the 8ths.